# Summing Variable Mismatches

Tags: r

I have a dataset where the participants took a few 12 items twice.  I'd like to count the number of times in which `V1 != V2 & V3 != V4` and so forth in order to quantify the degree to which they paid attention.

`with(data, 'V1' != 'V2')` returns a logical TRUE for the entire dataset.  I also tried creating a function for this but I can't get it to operate over the different variables.  It also seems like I'm reinventing the wheel given the existence of `identical()`.

```
score.mismatch <- function(data,...) {
mis <- 0
if (data$V1 != data$V2) {
    mis <- mis + 1
    return(mis)
}
if (data$V3 != data$V4) {
    mis <- mis + 1
    return(mis)
} 
    # And so on
return(mis)
}
```

Thanks for any feedback and tips.

Comment: if @DWin's solution answers your question, dont forget to indicate as such by marking the checkmark next to it

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Thanks.  I'm still figuring out the StackOverflow etiquette.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you the same result:

```
with(data, sum( sum(V1 != V2), sum(V3 != V4) ) )
```

TRUE is 1 when coerced to numeric. If you want it in a function:

```
mismat <- function(df){
            mis <- with(df, sum( sum(V1 != V2), sum(V3 != V4) ) ) }
```

There are some issues that can arise in using `with` inside functions which I don't entirely understand but I do not think they would arise here unless your argument to `mismat()` did not have columns with those names.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important issues in the code pasted in your question that are likely giving you trouble

First, the quotes around the variable names in your `with` statement are indicating to compare two literal strings, `"V1"` and `"V2"`. Whereas without the quotes it would say to compare the *objects called* `V1` and `V2`
This example might clrify:

```
  df <- data.frame(V1=11:13, V2=1:3)

   #   df looks like: 
   #     V1 V2
   #   1 11  1
   #   2 12  2
   #   3 13  3

  # CORRECT:  we paste the values within V1 and V2
  with(df, paste(V1, V2, sep="~"))
  [1] "11~1" "12~2" "13~3"

  # INCORRECT:  we paste the strings "V1" and "V2".
  #            There is no connection between them and df
  with(df, paste("V1", "V2", sep="~"))
  [1] "V1~V2"
```

Second, within your function: 
Inside each `if` clause, you have a `return` statement. That implies that upon hitting a single `TRUE` value, that the function should cease from continuing. 
But from what you indicate, I believe that you do not want that behavior.

You likely would want to remove the `return` statements inside the `if` clauses, and leave only the last one.  Although, even more likely, you would probably want to use @DWin's suggestion ;)